# Debug surefire plugin itself

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm running some tests via surefire plugin.
For some reason, surefire terminates the VM and doesn't show meaningful information when I run maven with "mvn test -e".

I would like to debug the jvm spawned by surefire and see why it breaks.

Any idea on how to it?

Thanks,
Nadav

---

That's the link to log:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=95140326977648244849

Comment: You can do that of course (a bit complicated but possible) but it is very likely that you won't get additional info out of it. Could you post the stacktrace with `mvn -X clean test` so that we can take a look?

Comment: Sure - thanks! Posting it in a second..

Comment: I would suggest to use mvnDebug  and configure your ide to the debug port...

Comment: @khmarbaise - thanks. I'm using Eclipse. Should I download the source code of surefire and set it as the project I want to debug?

Comment: @Tunaki - I've just noticed I didn't upload the logs (it failed during the save). I've add a link to the log.